# Внедрение зависимостей MVC, Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Есть две модели:

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Название курса")]
    public string Title { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Описание курса")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Стоимость курса")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    //Configure 1 to many and NavigationProperty
    //foreighn key
    public int? CurrentTeacherId { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Обязательно для заполнения")]
    [Display(Name = "Опыт")]
    public int Expirience { get; set; }

    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

Я реализовал обобщённый интерфейс

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    void Add(T item);
    void Update(int id, T Item);
    List<T> GetAllRecords();
    T GetById(int id);
}
```

Переопределил методы

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DataContext Context;

    public BaseRepository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        Context = dataContext;
    }

    public void Add(TEntity item)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(item);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public List<TEntity> GetAllRecords()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Update(TEntity Item)
    {
        Context.Entry(Item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Создал ещё один класс, в котором добавил 2 интерфейса `ICourseRepository`, `ITeacherRepository` (т.е. в них расширяем наши интерфейсы методами).
И соответственно класс `CourseRepository`

```
public interface ICourseRepository : IRepository<Course>
{
    //List<Course> GetCoursesByTeacherId(int teacherid);
}

public interface ITeacherRepository : IRepository<Teacher>
{

}

public class CourseRepository : BaseRepository<Course>, ICourseRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private ICourseRepository _courseRepository;
    //private readonly ITeacherREpository _teacherREpository;
    //ITeacherREpository teacherREpository

    public CourseRepository(DataContext dataContext, CourseRepository courseRepository) : base(dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _courseRepository = courseRepository;
        //_teacherREpository = teacherREpository;
    }

    //public List<Course> GetCoursesByTeacherId(int teacherid)
    //{
    //    Teacher teacher = _teacherREpository.Find(p => p.TeacherId == teacherid);

    //    if (teacher != null)
    //    {
    //        List<Course> asd = _dataContext.Courses.Where(p => p.Teacher.TeacherId == teacher.TeacherId).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    //    }

    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}
}
```

Как я теперь могу использовать весь функционал для методов в контроллере, и использовать Ninject. Здесь как то я застрял.
В контроллере написал след. код.

```
IRepository<Course> repository;
    public HomeController(IRepository<Course> _repository)
    {
        repository = _repository;
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ICourseRepository>().To<CourseRepository>();
        repository = kernel.Get<ICourseRepository>();
    }
```

Но выдаёт ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интерфейсы вы добавили, а где их регистрация в DI контейнере?

Comment: Вы в конструкторе контроллера пытаетесь что то зарегистрировать? Это делается в Startup классе. К моменту, когда дело дойдет до контроллера, всё уже должно быть давно зарегистрировано

Comment: Не зарегистрировал в Startup классе, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема заключалась в регистрации зависимостей в Global.Asax файле. как и ответил tym32167. (у меня они не были зарегистрированы), данный код для обобщённых интерфейсов (ниже).
мои действия:

```
NinjectModule module = new NinjectRegistrations();
var kernel = new StandardKernel(module);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

В global.asax файле

```
NinjectModule module = new NinjectRegistrations();
var kernel = new StandardKernel(module);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

И в контроллере:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IRepository<Course> repository;
    public HomeController(IRepository<Course> _repository)
    {
        repository = _repository;
    }

    public ActionResult GetAllCourses()
    {
        return View(repository.GetAllRecords());
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем кусок кода в виде скриншота?

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил